# How do I get the business days in a week with PHP given the range and current week as params?

Tags: php, date

how do I compute the business days in a week given the parameters: start date, end date and current week? The duration of the range for the start date and end date may go over a year.

edit:
thanks for the welcome! business days are from mon-fri.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Define "business days." Where? In what country? Including bank holidays? Including holidays like Christmas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code bellow displays only business days between two dates :

```
$start_date = '2010-02-01';
$end_date = '2010-02-28';

$next_date = $start_date;
while ($next_date != $end_date) {
        if (date('N',strtotime($next_date)) < 6) echo $next_date."\n";
        $next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_date.' +1 day'));
}
```

date('N',$sometimestamp) gives you the numeric representation of the day of the week : 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php